# Краузябры в компоненте catalog и "не удается обнаружить код вызова компонента"

Tags: php, битрикс

Существуют краузябры в компоненте catalog и не удается обнаружить код вызова компонента.  Скажите, пожалуйста, почему.
как это можно исправить?

Файл htacess

```html
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
  php_value display_errors 1
  php_value mbstring.func_overload 2 
  php_value mbstring.internal_encoding utf-8 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 day"  
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uni.loc
RewriteRule (.*) http://uni.loc/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Как это сделать? Дальше, как делать, версия битрикса 12.5

Comment: Если включить экстрасенса, я могу предположить что речь может идти о bitrix, но не версии, ни нормального описания тут нет. да и слово `краузябры` первый раз вижу. А если всё же речь идёт о битриксе, то запустите проверку сайта, в админке, и она Вам всё расскажет. Вероятнее всего у вас неправильно настроен файл .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Административная часть → Настройки → Инструменты → Проверка системы →
>   Начать тестирование.

Результат присылайте сюда (-:

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9icr5i

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9icrkj

Comment: я сменила на хостинге файл php.ini . Далее,  возникли следующие ошибки http://prntscr.com/9id3t6

Comment: а ссылка "Исправить" не помогает?

Comment: Перво-наперво надо избавиться от красной надписи про mbstring.